# Why does "print /regex/ ? print a : print b" put "1" before each line?

Tags: perl

When I run the below Perl one-liner, it prints `1` in front of each line, which I don't want it to. All it should do is comment lines that match `root`.

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | perl -ne 'print /root/ ? print "\#$_" : print $_'
1daemon:x:1:1::/:
1bin:x:2:2::/usr/bin:
#root:x:0:0:Super-User:/root:/usr/bin/bash
1sys:x:3:3::/:
```

Comment: Why do you have `print` in three places?

Comment: You wanted a leading boolean test. You have a leading `print` statement. `print` on "does `/root/` match" is presumably returning `1` (and then evaluates to `true` or `false` as approriate.. Drop the first `print`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're printing the return value of `print`, which is successful so evaluates to `1`.

I would suggest changing your code to this:

```
perl -pe '$_ = "#$_" if /root/' /etc/passwd
```

Here I'm using the `-p` switch, so that `$_` is always printed. A `#` is added before the start of the line when `/root/` matches.

If you want to do the `print` explicitly, use this:

```
perl -ne 'print /root/ ? "#$_" : $_' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: `perl -pe 's/^(?=root:)/#/' /etc/passwd`

Comment: @TLP Sure, as they say, there's more than one way to do it!

Answer (score 8):

You only need one `print`; don't put two more inside the ternary!

```
perl -ne 'print /root/ ? "\#$_" : $_' </etc/passwd
```

As it is, you're unconditionally printing the return value of whichever `print` the ternary operator executes -- hence, the `1`.

Comment: @TLP, my use of stdin redirection was deliberate there, to show something that's a universal replacement for (and just as performant as) `cat inputfile | foo`, whereas passing a filename on a command line only works for a limited subset of tools (though perl is indeed among them). Thus, changing `</etc/passwd` to `/etc/passwd` does have some impact on authorial intent, so I hope you understand the rollback. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting a leading `1` on every line because it is the result of the evaluation of the `/root/ ? case_true : case_false`.

To solve it, just get rid of the initial `print` before `/root/`:

```
cat /etc/passwd | perl -ne '/root/ ? print "\#$_" : print $_'
#                           ^
#                   no print!
```

Note also there is no need to `cat file | perl`. Instead, say `perl file`:

```
perl -ne '/root/ ? print "\#$_" : print $_' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I might bow out here -- you were a second or two faster than me, and Tom's answer is more comprehensive.:)

Comment: Why 2 print statements and the ternary operator in void context?  Duffy's answer seems more correct to me.

Comment: @tjd not sure what you mean here. The question is about "why" it is printing 1 everywhere. There are many ways to do the same and, as I said before, once you have three similar answers at the same moment, you have to be careful on what you edit not to get the exact same answers.

Answer (score 2):

How about just

```
perl -pe 'print "#" if /root/' /etc/password
```

Which prints every line anyway because of the `-p`, but also prints a hash character first if the regex matches